# Is this series convergent? (which could not be solved by comparison theorems)

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $$c_n=\sum_{k=1}^{2n-1}\frac{1}{k^a}\left(\frac{1}{(2n-k)^a}-\frac{1}{(2n+1-k)^a}\right)$$

Can we show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n$ converge?

If $a>1$, then by Kay K., it is OK to be convergent.

For $1/2<a<1$, can we show its convergence? Thank you.

Comment: What is the value  of $a$?

Comment: I think $a>0$..

Comment: Now I think a > 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
0<c_n&=\sum_{k=1}^{2n-1} \frac1{k^a}\left(\frac1{(2n-k)^a}-\frac1{(2n+1-k)^a}\right)\\
&<\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac1{1^a}\left(\frac1{(2n-k)^a}-\frac1{(2n+1-k)^a}\right)+\sum_{k=n}^{2n-1} \frac1{n^a}\left(\frac1{(2n-k)^a}-\frac1{(2n+1-k)^a}\right)\\
&n-k\mapsto m,\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad 2n-k\mapsto p\\
&=\sum_{m=1}^{n-1} \frac1{1^a}\left(\frac1{(n+m)^a}-\frac1{(n+m+1)^a}\right)+\sum_{p=1}^{n} \frac1{n^a}\left(\frac1{p^a}-\frac1{(p+1)^a}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{(n+1)^a}-\frac1{(2n)^a}+\frac1{n^{a}}-\frac{1}{n^a(n+1)^a}\\
&<\frac{2}{n^a}
\end{align}
Therefore $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_n$ converges if $a>1$.